# Custom scoring metric sklearn logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's say I have the following custom loss function that I'm using in sci-kit learn.  In this case I'm only scoring the observations where my model scores above 0.8.

```
def customLoss(y_true, y_pred):
    a = pd.DataFrame({'Actuals':y_true, 'Preds': y_pred})
    a = a.query('Preds > 0.8')
    return(precision_score(a['Actuals'], a['Preds']))

param_grid = {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}
scorer = make_scorer(mf.customLoss ,greater_is_better = True)
grid = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(class_weight = 'balanced'), param_grid = param_grid, scoring = scorer, cv = 5)
```

However, let's say I wanted to make the threshold (0.8) configurable.  Obviously I would need to add a third argument to my loss function like this:

```
def customLoss(y_true, y_pred, threshold):
        a = pd.DataFrame({'Actuals':y_true, 'Preds': y_pred})
        a = a.query('Preds > @threshold')
        return(precision_score(a['Actuals'], a['Preds']))
```

However, I'm a little confused on where in the `make_scorer` function I'd put this third argument?

Comment: Please, refine your question to a single problem in order to make it clear.

Comment: edited my question!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grid = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(class_weight = 'balanced'), param_grid = param_grid, scoring = 'metric_you_want', cv = 5)
```

Comment: I guess I'm also confused about what such a function would look like

Comment: You should be able to pass a callable as well, to the scoring parameter. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring

Comment: how does the syntax look?

Comment: couldn't find in the docs where a third argument would be placed.

Comment: Pasindu any ideas here?

Comment: I would try using the make_scorer function
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer